# Accessing web page content using java networking

Tags: java, networking

This is the piece of code that I am writing in order to read five lines from the web page. But instead of the content I end up getting the html tags . I have tried to find out online and it says proxyhost and proxyport need to be set (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/_setProxy.html), But I cant figure out what should be my proxyhost and proxyport. How can I find that ?

BufferedReader keyboard;
String inputLine;

```
keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.print("Please enter the name of a website ");
System.out.flush();        /* Make sure the line is printed immediately. */
inputLine = keyboard.readLine();


URL webpage=new URL("http://"+inputLine+".com/");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webpage.openStream()));
String reading_five_lines;
int count=0;
while((reading_five_lines=br.readLine())!=null||count<5)
{
    count++;
System.out.println(reading_five_lines);
}
```

Comment: check your browser settings to find out what's the proxy. And use httpclient instead, so you can deal with redirections

Comment: Go to the site in the browser and use the browser's 'view source' function. THAT is what the browser gets and THAT is what you get. The browser however is a complex monster which can take that content, interpret it and render it using any additional CSS and JS content and images that comes along with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think setting a proxy is going to help you here.

The code you are seeing (I'm assuming because you didn't post the output) is the literal HTML code of the website.

If you want the readable (Human Friendly) version you'll have to run it through a HTML parser.

A quick google search brought this result up.

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/